# matplotlib, copy and restore transparent region

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to copy-paste 2 **transparent** figures into a third.

Figure 1 (transparent):

[image: figure1]

Figure 2 (transparent):

[image: figure2]

Figure 3:

[image: figure3]

Failed :

[image: failed]

Transparency:

```
figure.patch.set_visible(False)
axes.patch.set_visible(False)
```

Copy:

```
region1 = canvas1.copy_from_bbox(figure1.bbox)
region2 = canvas2.copy_from_bbox(figure2.bbox)
```

Paste:

```
canvas3.restore_region(region1)    
canvas3.restore_region(region2)
```

I think the matplotlib buffer is totally overridden by the second **restore_region()**, so the canvas update only paints **region2**. Is it correct ? Is there a workaround ?

Full source code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def create_canvas(rect, transparent, title=None):
    figure = plt.figure()
    canvas = figure.canvas
    axes = figure.add_axes(rect)
    if transparent:
        figure.patch.set_visible(False)
        axes.patch.set_visible(False)
    axes.plot(np.random.rand(5))
    if title:
        axes.set_title(title)
    return canvas, figure, axes

canvas1, figure1, axes1 = create_canvas([0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4], transparent=True, title="figure1")
canvas2, figure2, axes2 = create_canvas([0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 0.6], transparent=True, title="figure2")
canvas3, figure3, axes3 = create_canvas([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8], transparent=False, title="Click to merge figure1 and figure2")

canvas1.draw()
canvas2.draw()

region1 = canvas1.copy_from_bbox(figure1.bbox)
region2 = canvas2.copy_from_bbox(figure2.bbox)

def on_click(self):
    print("on_click")
    canvas3.restore_region(region1)    
    canvas3.restore_region(region2)
    canvas3.update()

canvas3.mpl_connect('button_press_event', on_click)

plt.show()
```

Comment: `restore_region` dumps "raw" rgb pixels.  It doesn't do compositing, so it doesn't matter how you have the transparency set.  What are you trying to do? If you'd like to have both axes on a figure, blitting isn't the approach you want (instead, add a new axes over the first one).

Comment: The reason why I wanted to use blitting is to speed up a figure with a lot of plots; when a plot change, I only want to redraw its layer, instead of redrawing everything.

Comment: Well, if you'd like to use blitting with transparency, you'll need to do the compositing yourself.  Blitting fundamentally works with RGB, not RGBA.  However, handling compositing yourself is likely overkill.  You're far better off redrawing in this case.  You can mix places where you blit and where you draw.